# PSQL Dump Files vary widely in size

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump

I have a running Django App with a PSQL database.
I am using the following command in order to backup the database daily :

pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost db_name >> "C:\Users\User\Documents\backup_%date:~-4%*%date:~3,2%*%date:~0,2%__%time:~0,2%*%time:~3,2%*%time:~6,2%.sql"

I am using Windows Scheduler to execute this command everyday, the problem is that for 3-4 days it works perfectly generating a file of approximately 45mb, and then it generates a file of 120mb for 3-4 days, and then it jumps to 200mb, this keeps going until I restard the server and then it goes back to generating 45mb files.

Note: the 45mb can be restored correctly, but the other files don't work properly, they only restore about 20% of all the data in my database.

I am not very familiar with PSQL, I didn't find anything about this issue online.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

```
pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost db_name >> "C:\Users\User\Documents\Dump.sql"
```

this command is creating the file when it runs for the first time and next time instead of replacing the file with a new one it is adding another full dump with the old contents since you are using '>>'. That sql will be invalid and not restorable and also file size will add up.

to fix that use single '>' and also at the beginning you can rename the old file if you don't want to loose it. For example:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost db_name > "C:\Users\User\Documents\Dump.sql"
```

Comment: I'd also consider using `-f "C:\Users\User\Documents\Dump.sql"` instead of `> "C:\Users\User\Documents\Dump.sql"`: it's probably less dependent on shell/environment.

Comment: in pg_dump docs there is not -f option.

Comment: It's there in the current doc (PostgreSQL 15) and even as far as the older doc available (version 7.1): https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html (see `-f file` or `--file=file`)

Comment: yes. In pg 15. But -f is for format. I use a bash shell to backup our db every 15 mins and store in s3 storage. I use the syntax I shared in my answer. For windows, you can write a batch file and execute that with the task scheduler.

Comment: no, `-F` is for `format`, but `-f` is for `file` for all versions.

Comment: Actually I am using a slightly different command I just didn't include it to make the question easily readable. My actual command is this : 
pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost db_name >> "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\backup_%date:~-4%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2%__%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%.sql"
So every file has its dump date as a name. And a new file is generated everytime. That's not the issue.

Comment: @MounirBenhalima Is there a chance that your tasks is triggered multiple times for whatever reason? You should probably try using `-f` (or single `>`)